# Why do browsers forbid non-SSL connections when a webpage was already served over HTTPS?

Tags: security, ssl, browser

Once a webpage is served over HTTPS, we can be fairly certain that they are who we intended.

At this point, the only security risk left is that the website itself is malicious or has a security vulnerability.

For example, you may enter your credit card details which are sent to their server, and their server could release those details to the public.

---

I'm now trying to figure out the reasons why browsers do not allow non-SSL connections when the webpage was already served over HTTPS?

For example, browsers will stop allowing non-SSL HTTP and WS content, and don't expose UDP or TCP socket APIs.

To me there is the exact same risk that they don't use SSL on their server anyway. If anything, HTTPS could now be giving a false sense of security.

I could only identify two reasons:

1. To prevent webpages from accidentally using non-SSL connections. So I can understand that a form or image should only allow HTTPS. But I believe that browsers should allow, for example, UDP sockets but must be created like so (confirming that the programmer is aware of security risks):

```
udp = new SomeBrowserAPI.CreateUDPSocket()
udp.amAwareThat("Nothing is encrypted over UDP and I should not send any sensitive data here")
udp.amAwareThat("I cannot confirm the identity of who I am sending data to or receiving data from")
```

2. A client-side developer should not have to worry about security risks, but rather UI etc. By being forced to communicate to the server over SSL, it is up to the backend developers to worry about security only. However, this is already not the case anyway. If you are a client-side developer, you could easily write malicious client-side code that reads password input and sends it to your own server, as long as your own server is also over SSL (although SSL might at least allow you to identify who was responsible).

Are there any other reasons? Are my reasons / solutions / info correct?

Comment: About the "udp.amAwareThat" incidentally you may want to have a look at https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf  It shows that many "SSL" libraries either have their default wrong, or expose an API that can be misused even involuntarily and hence bad things happen.

Comment: PS: SSL is dead since 20 years ago, the protocol is now called TLS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic post in Google's Web Fundamentals: [What is mixed content?](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

It is very basic, but lists three major threats: data authentication, data integrity and data confidentiality.

When you connect over UDP, you don't know

1. who actually serves your connection. It might have been intercepted by *enemies*;
2. whether the data received is actually the data sent. It might have been tampered by a *man-in-the-middle*;
3. who else have read your messages. *Big brother is watching you*.

Mixed content ruins the concept of secure webpages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand these problems with UDP. However, since the website was already served over HTTPS, we know that the websites intended JavaScript is running on your browser. The website is obviously not going to send sensitive data over UDP unless they aren't aware of security problems. But if they aren't aware of security problems, then they are probably doing things insecurely anyway on their server, and so supporting UDP on the client doesn't seem to have any additional risk. You already should just not trust that website regardless.Does it make sense what Im saying?

Comment: And a proper website would implement custom security measures on top of UDP if necessary.

Comment: IMHO, developers try to build modern browsers safe. They don't trust claims "Let me do smth unsafe, I know what I'm doing". And I can't blame them. In your case the proper solution could be to make a web-socket wrapper around the UDP source. Then JS can efficiently read/write without unsafe UDP sockets.

Comment: Well, I'm resorting to creating a browser extension for my needs